# Cannot get css Background-color good values on realhover()

Tags: hover, cypress

I want to validate the real color when I hover a button.

I can see the `realhover()` does it's thing, changing the color of the button but I always get the error:

> expected `<a.g-card__item-link>` to have CSS property `background-color` with the value `rgb(182, 222, 251)`, but the value was `rgb(207, 233, 252)`

The test code is:

```js
// get link button 1st card hover color before and after
cy.get('.g-card__item-link')
  .should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(207, 233, 252)') //color before hover

cy.get('.g-card__item-link')
  .realHover()
  .should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(182, 222, 251)')  //I should get this color on hover
```

Answer (score 9):

The browser has a CSS engine that computes style changes on certain events, like `hover`. This changes the visible render, but not the CSS properties in the DOM, which is why the same color is returned in the test *after* hovering.

To get the computed styles, use the [Window: getComputedStyle() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

An example from the [MDN :hover page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```html
<style>
  .joinBtn {
    width: 10em;
    height: 5ex;
    background-color: gold;
    border: 2px solid firebrick;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .joinBtn:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
</style>

<p>Would you like to join our quest?</p>
<button class="joinBtn">Confirm</button>
```

This can be tested as follows:

```js
const colors = {
  gold: 'rgb(255, 215, 0)',
  bisque: 'rgb(255, 228, 196)'
}

const computedStyles = ($el) => window.getComputedStyle($el[0])

cy.get('button')
  .should('have.css', 'background-color', colors.gold) 

cy.get('button')
  .realHover()
  .then(computedStyles)          // call getComputedStyle()
  .its('background-color')       // pick out background-color value
  .should('eq', colors.bisque)
```

[image]

---

The steps can be wrapped in a custom command, which can be made global by adding to `cypress/support/commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('computedStyle', {prevSubject: 'element'}, ($el, prop) => {
  return window.getComputedStyle($el[0])[prop]
})

cy.get('button')
  .realHover()
  .computedStyle('background-color')
  .should('eq', colors.bisque)
```

---

#### Example finding the hoverable element

From [w3schools - How TO - Hoverable Dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) live demo page,

The `:hover` CSS rule is on the `<div class="dropdown">` rather than the `<button>` element.

You can find out via dev-tools, **Styles** panel and interactively checking the hover effect on for various elements.

[image]

Comment: Thx, but even with those lines i still have the same error, the expected color is not the Hover's one.  I am confused

Comment: It could be you have the wrong element. Take a look in the source (if you have it) for `:hover` in the style sheet.

Comment: If you don't have source, open dev-tools and explore around the element. In the **Elements** tab find your link, under **Styles** in the RH sub-panel click on **:hov** to open the control panel. Then check the **:hover** check box for each potential element - the one you need to select in the test will change color when you check it's hover toggle.